I have a problem with static files in Django. I tried all the configurations and I can't use the cs or js
I'm trying configure the static files and you already tried to do everything but nothing works and I don't know what else to do
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
{% block content %}


<div class="home">
    homa
</div>
{% endblock %}

.home {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    /* Otros estilos aquí */
}

solve it and be able to use the static files

do you run in debug mode? If you don't use debug mode then you need to run with Apache or Nginx which will send static files.

Django doc: How to deploy static files | Django documentation | Django

If you are serving static files in development the make sure you have DEBUG=True and had added the static URL to your projects urls.py as shown in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development this link.

I ran into the same issue just a week ago. I found out that the path command is not correct.
Here is what I used that worked:
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

Then under Templates I used it like this:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        ...
        ...
        ...

It is an example. I used it for templates, you can use it the same way for your static files. It just shows how to create and use the BASE_DIR variable.
Also check the slash before: /static/
You might have to remove it so it becomes:
static/

